# Error with WebBrowser control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application in which I am using a `WebBrowser` Control. I load a local HTML file into the browser control. When I build and run the application, I get the following error:

[image]

I have noticed that this error does not show in all computers.
I am using the following statement to browse to the HTML file:

`webBrowserMap.Navigate(new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Resources/MAP.html"));`

The `WebBrowser` control is in a `UserControl` which I am adding to the window. When I open the designer(XAML) view of the window, I get this error.

I have observed that if I put the file in the path where I am getting the error, then the error is gone.

Comment: Have you used some resource from this path? Seems like your are getting this error on the systems where this resource is not present. Try to catch  this exception and share the full exception.

Comment: @prem: no, I have not used any resource from that path.

Comment: Break your code when you get this exception and share the exception. Also if possible share the piece of code block where your are getting it.

Comment: @prem: Even without executing the code, when I open the design view of the window, I get the error.